# React-native-reanimated: is there a way to remove a component from the dom when scrolling rather than hide it with style?

Tags: react-native, animation, scroll, react-native-reanimated, react-native-reanimated-v2

I'm able to hide a react-native element using `useAnimatedStyle` and returning a style that I can apply to my element like `opacity: 0` for instance.

But I don't find any way to remove the element from the dom.
Using

```
const handleScroll = useAnimatedScrollHandler(
  {
    onScroll(event) {
      currentPositionY.value = withTiming(event.contentOffset.y, {
        duration: 10,
      });
    },
  },
  []
);
```

I can only retrieve the value of `currentPositionY` inside `useAnimatedStyle` but I would like to find a way to do it directly in the rendering part like:

```
{currentPositionY > 50 ? <MyComponent/> : null}
```

Is there a way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the [useAnimatedReaction](https://docs.swmansion.com/react-native-reanimated/docs/api/hooks/useAnimatedReaction/) hook.

1. Create a state that controls the element visibility in the DOM
2. Use the useAnimatedReaction hook, and pass your sharedValue as a dependency
3. Inside the hook set your visibility state to false based on your logic.

Comment: Thanks, I tried this:
   useAnimatedReaction(
      () => currentPositionY.value,
      (result, previous) => {
        if (result > 200) {
          setIsHeaderCollapsed(true);
        }
      },
      [currentPositionY]
    );
And when result > 200 the app crashes

Comment: @Simon You should use 'runOnJS' method for setting the state.
[More about it](https://docs.swmansion.com/react-native-reanimated/docs/api/miscellaneous/runOnJS/)